# Do you know an alternative site for RXTX download?

Tags: rxtx

RXTX site http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download has been down for a while. Do you know an alternative site to download the latest rxtx lib for windows, linux and raspberry pi?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's 2 working links :
                http://www.jcontrol.org/download/rxtx_en.html
    http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/r/Downloadrxtx22jar.htm

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You can download binaries from the bellow link

https://code.google.com/p/c328r-java/downloads/detail?name=rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip&can=2&q=