# Connect R1240IB qID Wearable Bluetooth UHF RFID Barcode reader with Java programme through USB?

Tags: java, bluetooth, usb, rfid

I have to connect RFID reader with my java project. I installed all necesary driver for this device and imported all necesary Libraries. I used Eclipse program to writing my java project.
Am beginner with RFID readers. The below code doesn't work. Please help me.

```
package com.caen.RFIDLibrary;

import com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDException;
import com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDLogicalSource;
import com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDPort;
import com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader;
import com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReaderInfo;
import com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDTag;

public class reader_com {



    public static void main (String[] args) throws CAENRFIDException{



    CAENRFIDReader MyReader = new CAENRFIDReader(); //Create myObject

    CAENRFIDReaderInfo Info = MyReader.GetReaderInfo(); // Create Object for reader info

        String Model = Info.GetModel(); //Get info about model
        String SerialNumber=Info.GetSerialNumber(); // Get info about serialNumber
        String FWRelease = MyReader.GetFirmwareRelease();   // Get info about FW


    MyReader.Connect(CAENRFIDPort.CAENRFID_USB, "COM13"); // Open a connection
    CAENRFIDLogicalSource MySource = MyReader.GetSource("Source_0, Source_1"); // Choose Source 0-->RFID tags 1-->Barcode
    MySource.SetQ_EPC_C1G2(3); // set Q Value

    CAENRFIDTag[] MyTags = MySource.InventoryTag(); 

    if (MyTags.length > 0){
    System.out.println(Model);
    System.out.println(SerialNumber);
    System.out.println(FWRelease);
    }




MyReader.Disconnect();  
    }       
}
```

And i get back this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader$IOBuffer.access$1800(CAENRFIDReader.java:228)
at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader$CAENRFIDOutPacket.AddHeader(CAENRFIDReader.java:2701)
at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader.GetReaderInfo(CAENRFIDReader.java:3183)
at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.reader_com.main(reader_com.java:20)
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful - can you be more specific ?

Comment: i get back this error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader$IOBuffer.access$1800(CAENRFIDReader.java:228)
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader$CAENRFIDOutPacket.AddHeader(CAENRFIDReader.java:2701)
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader.GetReaderInfo(CAENRFIDReader.java:3183)
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.reader_com.main(reader_com.java:20)

Comment: You should add this exception message to your question, along with any other relevant information that might help someone debug your problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get any information about the reader (or call any other method of the `CAENRFIDReader` object), you **first** need to connect to it. So the flow of your program would be like this:

```
CAENRFIDReader myReader = new CAENRFIDReader();
myReader.Connect(CAENRFIDPort.CAENRFID_RS232, "COM13");

CAENRFIDReaderInfo info = MyReader.GetReaderInfo();
String model = info.GetModel();
String serialNumber = info.GetSerialNumber();
String fwRelease = myReader.GetFirmwareRelease();

CAENRFIDLogicalSource mySource = myReader.GetSource(...);
```

Also note, that if your reader is available on *COM13*, you would likely need to use `CAENRFIDPort.CAENRFID_RS232` and not `CAENRFIDPort.CAENRFID_USB`.

Comment: On what line you you get the error this time? Are you sure the reader is correctly connected to COM13?

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDException: @ No RS232 native support (install rxtxComm driver?)
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader.Connect(CAENRFIDReader.java:3303)
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.reader_com.main(reader_com.java:18)

Comment: Well, then I would suggest you read the error message and do what it tells you. I.e. add the [rxtxComm library](http://www.caenrfid.it/en/faq.jsp?Id=9&keywords=rs232) to your application class path. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568729/do-you-know-an-alternative-site-for-rxtx-download) on how to get rxtxComm.

Comment: i add rxtxComm library but now have this error---> CommPortIdentifier:static initialization()
RXTXCommDriver {}
Have not implemented native_psmisc_report_owner(PortName)); in CommPortIdentifier
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDException: @ No RS232 native support (install rxtxComm driver?)
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader.Connect(CAENRFIDReader.java:3303)
 at com.caen.RFIDLibrary.reader_com.main(reader_com.java:12)

Comment: Have you followed [these instructions](http://www.caenrfid.it/en/faq.jsp?Id=9&keywords=rs232)? If yes, are you using a 32 bit version of Java?

Comment: Have you tried to use different versions of the rxtxSerial library? E.g. the one included [here](http://code.google.com/p/serialcommx/).